# How can I use grep command to capture correlation ID along with java stacktrace and multiline message from log file

Tags: java, unix, exception, grep, stack-trace

In the log file, each request sent in will be automatically assigned with one unique correlation ID, for example `X-aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa` and `X-bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb` as in the log sample below that created by log4j.

```
2019-06-03 11:27:22,697|X-aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa|INFO |com.example.ExampleService|Start execute
2019-06-03 11:27:22,697|X-aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa|INFO |com.example.ExampleService|ENTRY| performIntegration()
2019-06-03 11:27:20,759|X-bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb|INFO |com.example.ExampleService|EXIT| executeService()
2019-06-03 11:27:20,759|X-bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb|INFO |com.example.ExampleService|EXIT| MyObject = This,
is
a
multiline log
message
2019-06-03 11:27:20,759|X-bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb|ERROR|com.example.ExampleAdapter|error
com.example.ABCRuntimeException: Network error
    at ...
    at ...
Caused by: ...
    at ...
    at ...
2019-06-03 11:27:22,698|X-aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa|INFO |com.example.ExampleService|EXIT| performIntegration()
2019-06-03 11:27:22,699|X-aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa|INFO |com.example.ExampleService|EXIT| executeService()
2019-06-03 11:27:22,699|X-aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa|ERROR|com.example.ExampleAdapter| another error
com.example.ABCRuntimeException: Network error
    at ...
    at ...
Caused by: ...
    at ...
    at ...
```

How can I grep the correlation id with multiline message and java stacktrace together? For example I want to grep `X-bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb`, then the expected output should be as per below

```
2019-06-03 11:27:20,759|X-bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb|INFO |com.example.ExampleService|EXIT| executeService()
2019-06-03 11:27:20,759|X-bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb|INFO |com.example.ExampleService|EXIT| MyObject = This,
is
a
multiline log
message
2019-06-03 11:27:20,759|X-bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb|ERROR|com.example.ExampleAdapter|error
com.example.ABCRuntimeException: Network error
    at ...
    at ...
Caused by: ...
    at ...
    at ...
```

Is linux grep command able to achieve this? Or is there any other recommended tools? However, I am not allowed to install new package on the production servers. The operation system is Red Hat 7.

Comment: @John1024, thanks for point out. Edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$ awk -F\| -v id='X-bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb' '/^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} /{f=0} $2==id{f=1} f' file
2019-06-03 11:27:20,759|X-bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb|INFO |com.example.ExampleService|EXIT| executeService()
2019-06-03 11:27:20,759|X-bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb|INFO |com.example.ExampleService|EXIT| MyObject = This,
is
a
multiline log
message
2019-06-03 11:27:20,759|X-bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb|ERROR|com.example.ExampleAdapter|error
com.example.ABCRuntimeException: Network error
    at ...
    at ...
Caused by: ...
    at ...
    at ...
```

#### How it works

- `-F\|`

  Use `|` as the field separator.
- `-v id='X-bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb'`

  Create an awk variable called `id` and assign to it the id of interest.
- `/^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} /{f=0}`

  If the current line begins with a date, set variable `f` to false (zero).
- `$2==id{f=1}`

  If the second field matches the desired id, set variable `f` to true (one).
- `f`

  If `f` is true, print the line.

Answer (score 0):

I hope that this will help:

you can use `-C n` in your grep command where n is an integer to determine the number of lines surrounding your grep word

`grep 'X-bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb' file -C 10`

will help
it will not give you exactly what you want, but it will help.